# How to get File names from a Document Library using a REST GetByTitle query and TypeScript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, typescript

I am firing this query:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyLib')/items?$select=Title,File/Name&$expand=File/Name
```

I am getting a bunch of files, I see the names I want when running the query in the browser:

```
<d:Name>INeedThisFileName.jpg</d:Name>
```

But they are nested in these properties:

```
/Items(717)/File</id><category term="SP.File" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'921b46e1-91cf-426d-ab11-9e59bd995f3e')/Items(717)/File" /><title /><updated>2020-05-17T22:20:03Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:Name>INeedThisFileName.jpg</d:Name></m:properties></content></entry></m:inline></link><title /><updated>2020-05-17T22:20:03Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml" /></entry><entry m:etag="&quot;1&quot;"><id>526c333a-59ef-47eb-9498-12d12973290d</id><category term="SP.Data.MyLibItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'921b46e1-91cf-426d-ab11-9e59bd995f3e')/
```

The problem is that if I add a Name property in the ListItem interface, I get "undefined" for all files.

```
export interface ISPList {
  Title: string;
  Name: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use pnp js to get file name.And I change interface ISPList to class ISPList .

Method 1:

```
web.lists.getByTitle('lib').items.select('Title','File/Name').expand('File/Name').get().then(response=>{
        console.log("------------------");
        response.forEach(element => {
          let file=new ISPList();
          if(element.File){
            file.Name=element.File.Name;
          }else{
            file.Name='';
          }          
          file.Title=element.Title;
          console.log(file);
        });
        console.log("------------------");
    });
```

[image: test result1]

Method 2:

```
const url = "/sites/dev/lib";
      web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(url).files.select("Title","Name").get().then(response=>{
          console.log("file2------------------");
          response.forEach(element => {

            let file2=new ISPList();
          if(element.Name){
            file2.Name=element.Name;
          }else{
            file2.Name='';
          }          
          file2.Title=element.Title;
          console.log(file2);
          });
          console.log("file2------------------");
      });
```

[image: test result2]